# How to get rid of horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I have problem with unwanted horizontal scrollbar.

I used this to see if any element is overflowing:

```
* {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

but I did not find any element that overflows.

Comment: `.main-container` is using `min-height: 100vh` so it's effectively 100% of the viewport height (hence it pushes the footer below the visible viewport), rather than what I expect you want, which is 100% of the remaining height (remaining = vh - header - footer). You'd likely need a `calc` or better still, use Bootstrap's flex classes.

Comment: @MatthewLayton Scrolling up and down isn't problem. Problem is scrolling left and right.

Comment: Your issue is `#nav-mobile` - when removing `width: 100vw` the scrollbar disappears. Try to  play with its CSS to try to find the best styles for it. I.E: instead of using `visibility: hidden` try to `display: none` for desktop. Or some other trickery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is `#nav-mobile`.

Instead of using `position: absolute;` use `position: fixed;`.

You want it fixed on mobile anyways. That's at least how people build mobile menus.
When using `absolute`, that *absolute* is in relation to the first positioned ancestor, therefore seems like it inherits some strange margins (even if left is `0`)